# Export data to an Excel .xlsx pre-formatted template

Tags: r, export-to-excel, xlsx, xlconnect, openxlsx

I would like to export some result datasets to several sheets of a "template" xlsx file which is already pre-formatted (size, format of cells, filter on header, etc... already existing in the template).
I just want to fill the template with the values (some equivalent of copy/paste only values from Excel).

I tried the `xlsx` / `openxlsx` packages but it doesn't work: this changes the styles of the worksheets.

I also tried the `XLConnect` package with the setStyleAction*(wb, XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")* setting, It only works for one of the sheets but not the others...

I am using R version 3.5.1 (32-bit) and Excel 2016

With `openxlsx`, I am using the code below :

```
Output_wb <- loadWorkbook(file = system.file("MyTemplate.xlsx"), package= "openxlsx"))
writeData(wb=Output_wb, sheet="Sheet1", Dataset2, xy = c(2,2), colNames = FALSE, rowNames = FALSE)
## Save workbook
saveWorkbook(Output_wb, "Summary_of_results.xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Could you show the code you tried using `openxlsx`? And describe what happens ("changes the styles of the worksheets")? I'm using this package for the same task frequently and have no problems.